# [Excel 2010 VBA]Cell format is changed after running VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having this problem working with VBA which I haven't figured out how to fix, and hence would love to ask some expert on here.

So my complication is that I have a cell whose value is AUG18 (In formula bar: **'AUG18**)

I was trying to writing a simple code to replicate the value of that cell to other cells below it. The code worked fine, but the format of the cell was changed after I ran the code.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Sub AutoFill()
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
End Sub
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the value transfer caused the original issue; copy/paste values seemed to work.

```
Sub AutoFill()
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the value in a Text function.
Text(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value, "mmmdd")

That's just a guess.